# trying to find the title of a book with Zeus and several muses

Tags: story-identification

The book I am looking for has the hero , a normal human male, falling in love with a strange girl looking for her sister because her father is getting angry.  It is later found out that the girls are muses and if the missing one isn't found Zeus , the father, will exact retribution... the hero works for a computer company and in the end they find the missing girl and Zeus rides a Harley. Also "The sound of silence" is more than a song title.

Comment: Probably not https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33830680-muse-song, as it's not a normal boy.

Comment: Congrats on finding your answer. ^_^ Welcome to the site. Feel free to ask more questions, or to look at the extant questions and trying to help solve them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Zeus and Company](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2012403.Zeus_and_Company)* by David Lee Jones. Summary from [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1114619798?book_show_action=true):

[image: Front cover of Zeus and Co.]

> To summarize, the muses have been trapped by a computer virus. Our nerdy hero is befriended by one of Zeus's sexy daughters, so that she can inspire him in the art of programming. Towards the final act Zeus intervines on his Harley. If you have the opportunity to read this please do, in the spirit that you would watch Attack of the Killer Tomatoes.

The muse he finds on his hard drive is Euterpe.

Found with search terms of `novel muse zeus harley`